# How to select the max primary key auto Increment in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, max, auto-increment

If I delete the max IDs (for example 9, 10,11) from the table, the `sql` will not begin from the max existing ID ! it begins with 12!

1. is it possible to let the `sql` add new id according to existing max id?
2. how to get the max primary key autoincrement in the table (the deleted one too)?

This code finds the existing only and not the deleted ids:

```
select max(id) from table1
```

Comment: If your `ID` is auto-incrementing, it's probably best to leave it alone. You'll have gaps in your ID's, but that is seldom a problem. It is possible to force it to number from `max(id)` on, but it's likely more hassle than its worth.

Comment: if you remove the gaps every time something is deleted, then you no longer have unique IDs. e.g. the thing represented by ID 11 is no longer the thing that was previously represented by ID 11. But most software (and arguably most people) would assume that it was. Semantically for your data doing this is a bad idea. And it's also unnecessary for your software to work.

Comment: ok, i can let it like that, but i would like to get the realy max(id) because the data-name in the row should have the id_name like that 12.jpg

Comment: What you like and what you need aren't always the same. As HoneyBadger say, the hassle  to make that happen isn't worthy, try to keep the OCD under control and let it be.

Comment: I just want to know the next MAX(id) , that is all. i mean question 2 of my Post

Comment: you mean you want to know the next available ID that hasn't been used yet? That's a bad idea if you're going to put it into a web page. By the time the user posts back the page containing the ID, someone else could have inserted rows into the database, meaning that ID is already taken. If you're doing an insert, just submit the data without an ID, let the DB create a row with the next ID available  _at that exact moment_ and return the new ID to your application so it can link it to the data. Don't attempt to guess IDs in advance, it will break when you have >1 users.

Answer (score 3):

> If I delete the max IDs (for example 9, 10,11) from the table, the sql will not begin from the max existing ID ! it begins with 12 !

That is correct.  There is nothing surprising or exclamation-worthy about this.  That's how RDBMSes work.

> 1- is it possible to let the sql add new id according to existing max id ?

Not easily at all.  As a matter of fact, it is so difficult, and any attempt to do it would be so tied to the particular RDBMS that you are using, (that is, so not portable,) that you are advised to not even try.  That's because RDBMSes are built for highly concurrent use, so they have to be able to prevent the possibility of different clients inserting inconsistent primary key values.

> 2- how to get the max primary key autoincrement in the table

There really is no such thing as a "max primary key autoincrement in the table", because it may be changing at a very fast rate as someone is inserting rows into the table, so by the time your `select max(id) from table1` would return a value to you, the actual max value in the database may already be different.

Comment: What you *really* want is the id that was issued when you inserted a row. Stop thinking of this as the "max id" or anything like that.  It is just the id that the newly inserted row received.  And in order to answer that question, you have to tell us in precisely what way you are accessing your database.  Is it JDBC?  Is it ODBC?  An ORM perhaps?  Please do tell.